# How to deploy ASP .NET core app with linux app service plan to azure using CICD pipelines?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, azure-app-service-plans

I have an .NET 5 project(in my bitbucket repo) and one linux app service plan in Azure. I want to create CICD pipeline and deploy my webapp. The problem I am facing is The default yml file generated by azure is for 'windows-latest' vmimage. How do I change yml file so that It works for liux app service plan.

What I have tried:

1. Used pre-generated yml file (with vmImage: 'windows-latest'), The build is successful and deployment is successful too but when I visit my website it shows **:( Application Error**.
2. Changed the vmImage to 'ubuntu-latest'. but now builds failed with error

> the current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For
> example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell.

This is my azure-pipelines.yml ( I have changed vmImage to 'ubuntu-latest'.)[image: azure-pipelines.yml]

Can someone please help me How should I change my yml file, so that it work for linux app service plan? I searched for the documentation but everwhere they deployed directly from visual studio. I don't need that.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of configuration, code or other similar text. Copy the original text to your question (and format it with the code format tool).

Comment: You have the task `VSBuild` which needs a Windows machine - change your pipeline to use `dotnet publish`, `dotnet test` etc. which is cross platform

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use the `VsBuild@1` pipelines task which allows you to build with MsBuild, and can automatically select the version of Visual Studio to build the solution with. This will not run on a Windows build agent.

For .NET Core, and .NET 5 and beyond you will want to switch to the `DotnetCliTask@N`

Here is the YAML reference for using [DotnetCliTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops).